# Redux saga race effect in pure javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, es6-promise, redux-saga

In redux saga we have `race` effect where we can pass named promises:

```
const { a, b } = yield race({     // will resolve if one of them resolves
   a: call(somePromise),
   b: call(somePromise2),
});

if (a) {
  // do something because "a" resolved
}

if (b) {
  // do something because "b" resolved
}
```

**Question**: Is there a way to implement such thing in pure javascript?

```
const { a, b } = Promise.race({
   a: somePromise1,
   b: somePromise2,
});
```

but this will fail because `Promise.race` accepts only arrays. Is there a way to make it work as redux saga?

Comment: You could write that as `const [a, b] = await Promise.race([somePromise1, somePromise2])`

Comment: @OluwafemiSule doesnt work

Comment: What do you mean doesn't work? What do you expect?